# A few using DynamoDB with node.js questions

Tags: node.js, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to learn node.js and do some stuff with DynamoDB and I have run into a few issues that i havent found any examples of that work. I have a table set up with 2 columns, username and score. Username is the primary key, score is the sort key.

**Problem 1**: I want to query a specific list of user's scores (WHERE score IN list). My test case is `"username":["usr1","usr2,"usr3"]`. Below is my code.

```
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const doClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-2'});

exports.handler = (event,context,callback) => {

let params = {
    TableName: 'highscores',
    KeyConditionExpression: "#u = :val",
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
    "#u": "username"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":val":event.username
    }
    //AttributesToGet: [ "username","score" ],
};

doClient.query(params, function(err,data){
    if(err){
        callback(err,null);
    }else{
        callback(null,data);
    }
});
};
```

**Problem 2**: I want to update a score on the table. When trying this, it error's out and says "The provided key element does not match the schema". If I put score in the key, it will only replace the record where the username and the score match. Test case is "username": "usr", "score": 998. below is that code.

```
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const doClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-2'});

exports.handler = (event,context,callback) => {
let params = {
    Key: {
        username: event.username,
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set score = :s",
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{
    ":s":event.score
},
    TableName: 'highscores'
};

doClient.update(params, function(err,data){
    if(err){
        callback(err,null);
    }else{
        callback(null,data);
    }
});
};
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks:)

Comment: Where're your key declarations?

Comment: I assume you are referring to Key:{} like I have in the second code. For the first one, i don't think the key is needed since i am using KeyConditionExpression and it works for a single user, just not a list.

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, I suggest you use [batchGet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#batchGet-property).

```
let params = {
  RequestItems: {
    TableName: 'highscores',
    Keys: [
      {username: 'usr1'},
      {username: 'usr2'},
      {username: 'usr3'},
    ],
    AttributesToGet: [ "username","score" ],
};

doClient.batchGet(params, function(err,data){
    if(err){
        callback(err,null);
    }else{
        callback(null,data);
    }
});
```

Your second issue is due to your table schema. The `username` is apparently your **partition key**.  Your **primary key** is made up of a partition key and a sort key, so you need to supply both for updates.

Comment: Thanks. The problem i see with your supplied code is that the number of users being obtained is determined. This will not be the case as it will change. For the second issue, if i supply both username and score, it will only update the record that matches both username and score. I need to find the record that matches only the username and update the score.

Comment: @user3648673 then you need to change your schema definition (in your `serverless.yml`file, right?). Define `username` as your primary key, and don't declare the `score` column.